# getting started with web scraping

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

First I want you to know that I'm quite new with html and css, and at the moment I don't know how to use Java Script. I was watching videos on how to make a web scraper and I have some questions:

I see a lot of tutorials doing web scraping in python and since I quite know python I was asking myself, what is better for web scraping? Python or Java Script, which should I use? Can I 'connect' a python program with html?

I need to use web scraping for a web site, I'm trying doing something that takes specific dats from other web site and then display them on my web site, so people can see them. Do you have any suggestion on how to get started?

Please notice that I'm not too good in english, there are no tutorials or video for web scraping in my language and excuse for the error in this post.

Comment: DevTips on YouTube has a great series on scraping with node (JavaScript).

Comment: Python is the most popular language for web scraping.

Comment: @Shijith and can I use It with html?

Comment: @evolutionxbox search for that but I couldn't find It not even in his playlists

Comment: look for flask/Django

Comment: @FlavioManna https://youtu.be/pixfH6yyqZk it wasn’t a series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can be used for web scraping, a popular choice is to use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) but usually you will need to  use a few packages to do more complex things as you are describing.

Here is a nice tutorial that should help you get started:

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/

In terms of the website you mention, you would need to create some kind of webapp using Flask/Django that will either populate a database with the information you are scraping or that will retrieve the information on request by a user of your website.

For the Javascript vs Python I am not sure as I have only used python. My experience has been very good with it but the following might give you more information: [What is the best language and tool for doing web scraping?](https://hashnode.com/post/what-is-the-best-language-and-tool-for-doing-web-scraping-cikhw77jc000lsf53sfzmjjf6)
, [I wrote a web scraper in four different languages.](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/4-languages-1-app-cf7d209d700d)

The following blog post might also be useful to you: [Building a Web Scraper from start to finish](https://hackernoon.com/building-a-web-scraper-from-start-to-finish-bb6b95388184)
(Disclosure: I haven't read this fully, only scanned it but it seems relevant to your question)